# Convert Column Letter to Column Number in vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net

The company I work for has a lot of legacy programs that I either use and/ or maintain.  Some are written in VBA, some in vbScript, and some on VB.net.  I am, overtime, cleaning up a lot of the code.  One thing I am trying to clean up now is in this vb.net application, it modifies an excel workbook but instead of creating a function that would convert the letter to a number, they did this:

```
Const colB As Integer = 2
Const colD As Integer = 4
Const colH As Integer = 8
Const colI As Integer = 9
Const colJ As Integer = 10
Const colK As Integer = 11
Const colL As Integer = 12
Const colM As Integer = 13
Const colN As Integer = 14
Const colO As Integer = 15
Const colQ As Integer = 17
Const colR As Integer = 18
Const colT As Integer = 20
Const colV As Integer = 22
Const colW As Integer = 23
Const colX As Integer = 24
Const colY As Integer = 25
Const colZ As Integer = 26
```

and there are a lot more letters than that.  I want to clean it up now and convert it to a function.  In VBA, I know how to do it:

```
Function GetColNum(ByVal ColLetter As String) As Long
    
    GetColNum = Range(ColLetter & "1").Column
    
End Function
```

and I found how to convert a number to a letter in vb.net:

```
Private Function GetColLetter(columnNumber As Integer) As String

    Dim columnLetter As String = String.Empty
    Dim modulo As Integer

    While columnNumber > 0
        modulo = (columnNumber - 1) Mod 26
        columnLetter = Convert.ToChar(65 + modulo).ToString() & columnLetter
        columnNumber = CInt((columnNumber - modulo) / 26)
    End While

    Return columnLetter
End Function
```

I cannot figure out how to convert a letter to a number in vb.net though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
Private Function GetColNum(columnLetter As String) As Integer

    Dim base As Integer = Asc("A") - 1
    Dim result As Integer = 0

    For Each c As Char In columnLetter.ToUpper()
        result = result * 26 + Asc(c) - base
    Next

    Return result

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be better off with an Enum in VB .Net.  To construct it using the Const's is pretty simple if you know how to Alt drag(hold the Alt key while dragging)

1. Create an enum
2. Copy and paste all of the Const's.  Looks like this,

   ```
   Enum MyEnum
       Const colB As Integer = 2
       Const colD As Integer = 4
       Const colH As Integer = 8
       Const colI As Integer = 9
       Const colJ As Integer = 10
       Const colK As Integer = 11
       Const colL As Integer = 12
       Const colM As Integer = 13
       Const colN As Integer = 14
       Const colO As Integer = 15
       Const colQ As Integer = 17
       Const colR As Integer = 18
       Const colT As Integer = 20
       Const colV As Integer = 22
       Const colW As Integer = 23
       Const colX As Integer = 24
       Const colY As Integer = 25
       Const colZ As Integer = 26
   End Enum
   ```

Now Alt Drag through 'As Integer' and press delete.

[image]

Then Alt Drag through 'Const' and delete.  You should have this,

```
Enum MyEnum
    colB = 2
    colD = 4
    colH = 8
    colI = 9
    colJ = 10
    colK = 11
    colL = 12
    colM = 13
    colN = 14
    colO = 15
    colQ = 17
    colR = 18
    colT = 20
    colV = 22
    colW = 23
    colX = 24
    colY = 25
    colZ = 26
End Enum
```

An example of how to use the Enum

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'debug single step this
    Dim col As MyEnum = MyEnum.colB

    Dim colNM As String
    colNM = col.ToString.Replace("col", "")
    Dim colNum As Integer
    colNum = col

    'number to Enum
    Dim someNum As Integer = 22
    col = DirectCast(someNum, MyEnum)
    colNM = col.ToString.Replace("col", "")
    colNum = col
End Sub
```